# How can I change Python version of pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I have the following situation:

[image]

Python version is **3.8.2**, but Python version of pip3 is **3.9**. How can I change it?

Comment: You probably have multiple python installations.
You can check the executable path with `which pip3` and `which python3` and you will see that they have a different location.

your PATH variable defines which python installation is picked first, you can check that with `echo $PATH`, what comes first is used first

Comment: Never use the `pip`, `pip3`, etc. scripts. Instead always call _pip_'s executable module for a specific Python interpreter explicitly: `pythonX.Y -m pip ...`. -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 3):

As the comments have already said, it looks like you have 2 python versions installed, so you either want to uninstall one of them or use `python3.8 -m pip` instead of just `pip3`